# Can I build an equation from just few observations?

Tags: estimation, prediction, missing-data, data-imputation

I have the following data that has 5 observations and 2 missed observatiosn. I want to build an equation that can help estimate the missed observations.

```
data<- structure(list(time = c(0L, 14L, 44L, 25L, 52L, 168L, 188L, NA, 
                             NA, NA, NA, NA), bending = c(81.5, 70.23, 60.414, NA, NA, 49.05, 
                                                          36.68, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note that the relationship might not be linear.

Comment: In general the method used to do this are called "imputation".  I'm not an expert in that area, but I doubt you could get a robust result with 5 data points.

Answer (score 0):

Without any prior knowledge, these data points tell you literally nothing about the missed observations. If you have some prior knowledge, e.g. about the smoothness of the function, then perhaps you can make an estimate. But five data points are very few!

It's probably best to draw a graph and sketch a line. That way, you won't be claiming any more than is really true, which is that you are guessing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really agree, this data is for my friend who is trying to solve a problem in his field and I am trying the best to help him. Thank you so much!